# I can't get matchtemplate in opencv to work

Tags: python, opencv

I have this bit of code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

haystack = cv.imread('cards4/deck 4.png', cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2)
grayhaystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

needle = cv.imread('cards4/eightofspades.png', cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2)
grayneedle =cv.cvtColor(needle, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv.imshow('Needle', needle)
cv.imshow('Haystack', haystack)

#methods available :[cv.TM_CCOEFF, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, cv.TM_CCORR, cv.TMO_CCORR_NORMED, cv.TM_SQDIFF, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]
result = cv.matchTemplate(grayhaystack, grayneedle, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)


min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
needle_w = needle.shape[1]
needle_h = needle.shape[0]
top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)
cv.rectangle(grayhaystack, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255,0), 2, cv.LINE_4)

cv.imshow('Haystack', grayhaystack)
cv.imshow('Result', result)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

I took the needle image directly on the haystack image and i tried every different methods available and i always get a bad result.

Is there any way to make this work

[correct size needle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTuDR.png)

[Haystack image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS3y7.png)

edit: I fixed the size of the image but it still doesn't give me a good result

Comment: Your needle image is much smaller than the same design in the haystack image. Search Google for multi-scale template matching in Python/OpenCV. Or resize the needle image to the size that matches that in the haystack image

Comment: Template matching is not scale or rotation invariant. So the template must be the same size and orientation to get a good match.

Comment: but i was careful to take a needle image of the same size this time and nothing has been rotated. So how come i don't get a good match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me in Python/OpenCV.

**I believe your main issues (after fixing the template size) are: 1) you cannot draw color on a grayscale image (without converting to 3 channels) and 2) that you did not save the output from drawing your rectangle.**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

haystack = cv2.imread('haystack.png')
grayhaystack = cv2.cvtColor(haystack, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

needle = cv2.imread('needle.png')
grayneedle =cv2.cvtColor(needle, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('Needle', needle)
cv2.imshow('Haystack', haystack)

#methods available :[cv2.TM_CCOEFF, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, cv2.TM_CCORR, cv2.TMO_CCORR_NORMED, cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]
result = cv2.matchTemplate(grayhaystack, grayneedle, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
needle_w = needle.shape[1]
needle_h = needle.shape[0]
top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)
output = cv2.rectangle(haystack, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow('Haystack', grayhaystack)
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
cv2.imshow('output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('haystack_needle.png', output)
```

Result:

[image]